# Unable to open stored procedure from Visual Studio 2008 Server Explorer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008-r2

I have VS2008 Team with SP1 installed.

I have a connection setup to my local SQL Server 2008 R2 (and also to a remote Oracle server). In the VS Server Explorer pane I can see stored procedures in both databases.

However with my desktop application solution loaded into VS, whenever I try from the Server Explorer to open any stored procedure or function to view the contents, or try to add a new stored procedure or function, Visual Studio displays an error:

> Specified cast is not valid

I have tried repairing VS2008/SP1 with no improvement.

This makes debugging apps using stored procedures difficult and time consuming so I am hoping someone can tell me what is wrong with VS, and how to fix it. it's not always been like this so I know it isn't a permanent bug in VS.

I have Allow Debugging and Allow SQL/CLR Debugging checked on the connection, but that makes no difference to the problem. It doesn't seem to matter if the connection uses Windows Authentication or SQL Server authentication.

Can anyone help by suggesting why this should be happening?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! I eventually spotted a 'General' tab in the VS Output pane which informed me of a problem with the ...DataTools package, contact your vendor blah blah, and the instruction to execute "devenv /resetskippkgs" to fix it. So I did that and Visual Studio restarted with the issue fixed.